# Effect of KeywordTokenizer on multi-valued fields

Tags: solr

If a multi-valued field is passed through a KeyWordTokenizer, will the entire content be returned a single token or as many tokens as the number of values?

Answer (score 0):

Would be multiple tokens as fed to Solr.

The multivalued field is stored basically as a single value with extra spacing between terms determined by the positionIncrementGap.

So even if you pass the field through a KeyWordTokenizer the tokens would technically be a Single token but with positionIncrementGap would behave Multivalued.

Comment: I want to use this multivalued field for building spellcheck index. Will SpellCheckComponent suggest individual matching value or the entire field value? @Jayendra

Comment: Spell Check usually suggests single words. You can use Collate to suggest multiple values.

Comment: using multivalued keyword field for spellcheck doesn't work at all.. I think entire field value will be used to compute distance against the mis-spelt word